# Similarity of list elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

I have ten lists and I want to get their 'similarity'. Here is the input I have:

```
data = [
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'SeasonNumber', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'SeasonNumber', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'Genres', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'LanguageOfMetadata', 'ReleaseDate', 'Studio', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'TVSeriesID', 'Locales', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Name', 'Synopsis', 'Products', 'SeasonNumber', 'Platform'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'LanguageOfMetadata', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'Genres', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'LanguageOfMetadata', 'ReleaseDate', 'Studio', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'TVSeriesID', 'Locales', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Name', 'Synopsis', 'Products', 'SeasonNumber', 'Platform'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'ReleaseDate', 'Genres', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales'], 
    ['RuntimeInMinutes', 'EpisodeNumber', 'Genres', 'ReleaseDate', 'Name', 'Platform', 'PlatformID', 'BaseURL', 'Languages', 'ArtworkURL', 'Synopsis', 'TVSeriesID', 'Products', '_NetworkName', 'ReleaseYear', '_ContentProviderName', 'Studio', '_StudioName', 'Type', 'Locales']
]
```

My current method is to compare the length of the set of those values with the total length. So in the above it would be:

```
>>> len(set(data))/len(data)
0.5
```

However this is quite crude, as I'd like to get a similarity that isn't "all-or-nothing". In other words, something like a conceptual similarity, where the above may have a 98% similarity (sorry if I'm having trouble explaining exactly what I want here -- but I mean to evaluate similarity as not just the list itself, but the similarity of its elements.

Comment: Are you considering the similarity of non-identical elements?  Would `['apple']` and `['apple1']` be entirely dissimilar lists, because they share no elements, or similar lists because their elements are very close?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh the elements themsleves would need to be identical. So apple != apple1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [datasketch library](https://ekzhu.github.io/datasketch/minhash.html) and its MinHash data structure. This is based on the [Jaccard Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) for sets, which is just the intersection (what they have in common) divided by the union (all possible elements).

Here is an example:

```
from datasketch import MinHash

data1 = ['minhash', 'is', 'a', 'probabilistic', 'data', 'structure', 'for',
        'estimating', 'the', 'similarity', 'between', 'datasets']
data2 = ['minhash', 'is', 'a', 'probability', 'data', 'structure', 'for',
        'estimating', 'the', 'similarity', 'between', 'documents']

m1, m2 = MinHash(), MinHash()
for d in data1:
    m1.update(d.encode('utf8'))
for d in data2:
    m2.update(d.encode('utf8'))
print("Estimated Jaccard for data1 and data2 is", m1.jaccard(m2))
```

Gives you an estimation of the similarity, if your sets are large. Otherwise, just use the built-in set operations:

```
s1 = set(data1)
s2 = set(data2)
actual_jaccard = float(len(s1.intersection(s2)))/float(len(s1.union(s2)))
print("Actual Jaccard for data1 and data2 is", actual_jaccard)
```

If you want to take the Jaccard similarity of more than two sets, just compute the pairwise-comparison and take the mean (average) of all the values:

```
from datasketch import *
import itertools
minhash_data = list()
for element in data:
    m = MinHash()
    for d in element:
        m.update(d.encode('utf-8'))
    minhash_data.append(m)

jaccard_sims = list()
for pair in itertools.combinations(minhash_data, 2):
    jaccard_sims.append(pair[0].jaccard(pair[1]))

average = sum(jaccard_sims) / float(len(jaccard_sims))
print("Average Jaccard similarity: {}".format(average))
```

> Average Jaccard similarity: 0.9512152777777778

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. How would you do this for ten objects though? The above compares two documents.

Comment: You could take the pairwise jaccard similarity of all of them. Then just take the mean of the numbers.

Comment: would you want to show an example of that using the input data I gave and then I'll go ahead and accept your answer?

Comment: Sure, I just added it.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want to get the similarity between two lists there are multiple ways to do that. Like @Nick Pandey Jaccard Similarity. Another ratio called the [tanimoto ratio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index#Tanimoto_similarity_and_distance) works well too. 
[image: tanimoto coeff]

This is my implementation:

```
def tanimoto (list1, list2):
    intersection = [common_item for common_item in list1 if common_item in list2]
    return float(len(c))/(len(a) + len(b) - len(c))
```

Now, to tackle your problem of having to compare between 10 lists at the same time. You can only compare two elements at the same time using something like the above. However your can develop your own logic to give you a rough idea of how similar everything is to each other.

For example, you could take the take the lists five at a time and compare, or the better option, compare the first two lists, store the tanimoto coeff, compare the next two and repeat. Finally take the average of the coeffs. It's better in code:

```
def grouped(iterable, n):
    return zip(*[iter(iterable)]*n)

coeffs = []
for i, j in grouped(data, 2): # data refers to the variable in the question
    coeffs.append(tanimoto(i, j))

similarity = sum(coeffs)/len(coeffs)
```

Hope this helps :)