# How to calculate the Jaccard index for multiple lists in python where the order is important

Tags: python, machine-learning, similarity

I want to calculate the Jaccard Index for more than two list, I found one solution here : [Similarity of list elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54599246/similarity-of-list-elements)
but it doesn't take into consideration the element order (the index) which important in my case.
I run this code :

```
 Selected_Features = [
[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
[1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],]

from datasketch import MinHash
from datasketch import *
import itertools
minhash_data = list()
for element in Selected_Features:
m = MinHash()
for d in element:
    m.update(str(d).encode("utf-8"))
    minhash_data.append(m)
jaccard_sims = list()
for pair in itertools.combinations(minhash_data, 2):
    jaccard_sims.append(pair[0].jaccard(pair[1]))

average = sum(jaccard_sims) / float(len(jaccard_sims))
print("Average Jaccard similarity: {}".format(average))
```

And the output:
Average Jaccard similarity: 1.0
which is not!!

Answer (score 0):

Given two sets of integers s1,s2 and s3, now for finding jaccard index
`intersect = s1 & s2 & s3 &... size = len(intersect) index = size/(len(s1)+ len(s2) +len(s3 - size)`

Comment: can you please provide a clear example using python code

Comment: I have tried this solution and it raised an error, although I don't think that it takes the index order into consideration